# Как из таблицы SQL-базы данных сделать scv-файл?

Tags: python, sql, база-данных

У меня есть некая база данных SQL. Мне необходимо при помощи операторов метода .execute() и модуля pandas преобразовать данную базу в csv-файл в коде python. Я смог додуматься только как мне получить список кортежей этой самой таблицы, а вот дальше понятия не имею... Помогите , пожалуйста, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если получить данные из MS SQL, то примерно так.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pymssql

def exec_sql(query):
    server = ''
    db_name = ''
    user = ''
    password = ''

    conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, db_name)

    try:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, ) 

    finally:
        conn.close()

    return df



query = '''
        select
        reg.value as value
        from Tab1 as reg (nolock)       
        '''

dfdate = exec_sql(query)

dfdate.to_csv('file.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```